# Kafka JDBC Connector SAP can't read table with name containing @ "Error Illegal initial character: @"

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, sap, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using JDBC connector to connect to SAP and read tables. Some of the tables have a name with `@` at beginning and JDBC return me this error:

> Illegal initial character: @

This is my connector configuration:

```
{
  "name": "sap-jdbc",
  "config": {
    "name": "sap-jdbc",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "10",
    "topic.prefix": "sap_",
    "table.whitelist": "DB.@MYTABLE",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sap://server:30015/",
    "connection.user": "user",
    "connection.password": "password",
    "retention.ms": "86400000",
    "mode": "bulk",
    "poll.interval.ms": "86400000",
    
  },
}
```

I tried this configuratons without result

```
"table.whitelist": "\"DB\".\"@MYTABLE\"",
"table.whitelist": "DB.\"@MYTABLE\"",
"table.whitelist": "DB.'@MYTABLE'",
"table.whitelist": "DB.\\@MYTABLE",
```

Did anyone solve this?

Comment: Maybe try `"@MYTABLE"`? Most SQL dialects don't allow `@` in unquoted identifiers.

Comment: it didnt work, i tried also \\@MYTABLE

Comment: How about `server:30015/?databaseName=DB;currentSchema=@MYTABLE`, or remove the symbol entirely?

Comment: If i remove, it doesent work because it try to read the table without @

Comment: The SAP company is the owner of several RDBMS (HANA, MaxDB, SyBase, etc.) Some SAP software may be connected to non-SAP RDBMS. Which RDBMS is it?

Comment: Could you post the detailed trace? Do you use Avro? See this known issue: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/426 (*"extend fields's name is not support prefix "@" ?"*)